# Razor Pages Password Input Box Keeps Displaying Default Dots

Tags: asp.net-core-3.1

Built Add and Edit pages in .NET Core 3.1 Razor pages. When Edit page displays, both the "Password" and "Confirm Password" input boxes render empty as they should. When the Add pages displays, the "Confirm Password" input renders empty but the "Password" input renders with 15 default dots already entered. The input box code seems exactly the same on both pages:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label asp-for="User.user_password"></label>
    <input type="password" class="form-control" asp-for="User.user_password" />
    <span asp-validation-for="User.user_password"></span>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label asp-for="User.confirm_password"></label>
    <input type="password" class="form-control" asp-for="User.confirm_password" />
    <span asp-validation-for="User.confirm_password"></span>
</div>
```

Tried adding `value=""` but it still rendered the default dots. I'm not populating the inputs on the backend with anything. Any ideas?

[image: Add Inputs]
[image: Edit Inputs]

Comment: Maybe problem is in browser autofill, did you try in some other browser?

Comment: Genato, thank you that was it! Can't believe I didn't even think of trying that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update on my comment.

If problem is in browser autofill, you could try to clear autofill for that domain.

[How to clear saved auto fill passwords in chrome](https://support.clio.com/hc/en-us/articles/360008609034-How-do-I-Clear-Saved-Auto-Fill-Passwords-in-Google-Chrome)

Answer (score 0):

add autocomplete="off" to html

```
 <input type="password" class="form-control" asp-for="User.confirm_password" autocomplete="off" />
```